# nonlinear transformation vs. nonlinear regression

Tags: regression, linear-model

When the variance of a regression model is not a constant (heteroscedasticity problem), why would we have to make nonlinear transformations to linearise the model INSTEAD of fitting a nonlinear regression like the polynomial regression?

Comment: My understanding is that where linear regression using linear algebra directly yields parameters for the global error minimum, non-linear fitting methods generally require a starting set of parameters to iteratively refine - if those initial parameter values are near a local error minimum, the non-linear solver can easily return parameters for that local minimum. Finding good initial parameter values - values near the global minimum - can be difficult, and this difficulty is completely avoided with regression using linear algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of model should depend on the scientific background, while aiming for simplicity.

For instance, if we were modelling an immune response that was supposed to have an exponential growth phase, then using a logarithm transform would seem natural, and if doing a linear regression made sense afterwards, that was great.

On a different example, if we were studying chemical equilibria and in that model there were a power relation between the concentration of the molecules, using $x^a$ might be the way to go (or a logarithm, if we wanted to know $a$).

Finally, if we have a simple model that works, there is no point in aiming for a harder model.

Therefore, if the scientific background supports a polynomial relation and does not support an exponential relation, a polynomial regression should be preferred.

Looking specific at the problem of heteroscedasticity, if the variance of the dependent variable changes monotonically with the independent variable, we have a clue that perhaps there is a power relation between the variables, that can be studied by doing a log-log transformation, or an exponential relation, where we can try to do the log of the dependent variable.
The advantage with these approaches is that if the linear regression on the transformed variables makes sense from the scientific background, we will have a simpler model than doing a polynomial regression.

An related problem when modelling is the risk of [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting). That is another reason to prefer simpler models over more complicated ones (with more parameters).